# Semicircle having inscribed circle with radius $r$ ; how to prove that $r=\sqrt{ab}$?

Tags: circles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPJqC.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2n74.jpg)
Circle with radius r touches both altitudes, diameter and arc of semicircle.

Prove $r=\sqrt{ab}$ or square root of product of a and b. I have used $\sin(A+B)$, formula cosine rule but couldn't solve it. Please help and cope up with the drawing I think it's understandable.

Comment: Very strange circle  !

Comment: Didn't you understand the question and was the figur not able to interpret the question.please answer and stop excusing.

Comment: I am expecting answers from this site but people only complains

Comment: It is a matter of **politeness** towards us to provide figures that are "neat". It is so easy now with tools like Geogebra / Desmos, etc. Moreover, it will be  beneficial to you: in the process of construction, you will discover useful properties for solving your problem like the fact that the center of your semicircle, the center of the circle and the point of tangency (of the semicircle and the circle) are **aligned**.

Comment: Besides, your figure looks like the left vertical line segment is a radius of the semi-circle, otherwise said, is $a$ the radius of the semi-circle ?

Comment: I have solved your problem, using Pythagoras. If you want to cooperate by sending a correct drawing, we can discuss.

Comment: I am new here and don't know much of using it the most.so can we contact through WhatsApp.request.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use other means. Once you have erased your previous drawing and replaced it by a sufficiently accurate one **with letters for the important points**, I give you strong hints towards the solution.

Comment: I am trying to do so.

Comment: I have done it and tried my best.this was the exact one I have been given to solve that i couldn't even trying my level best.

Comment: Please help now.

Comment: a and b are any line segments not the centre of semicircle

Comment: Your drawing is indeed much better but you should have placed the centers of the circle and the tangency point; What is your level of studies ? Wait for 10 minutes for an answer.

Comment: I am a high school student in india aspires to be best at maths but every time I get difficulty in solving new tough problems

Comment: I would be obliged to you for the answer.

Comment: I am interested in cricket and a fan of newzealand captain Kane Williamson that is why I had my username so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

With the notations of the figure (which takes into account the fundamental fact that two tangent circles are such that their centers are aligned with their point of tangency):

Pythagoras theorem applied to the blue right triangle gives:

$$(R-s)^2=c^2+s^2 \ \iff \ c^2=(R-s)^2-s^2\tag{1}$$

We read on the figure:

$$a=R+c-s, \ \ b=R-(c+s)$$

which implies :

$ab=(R-s)^2-c^2 \tag{2}$

Using (1) in (2), we get: $ab=s^2$

which indeed means that $$s=\sqrt{ab}$$.

---

Edit: I have included (green curve) the locus of the centers of the circles. It is a parabola with equation:

$$y=\frac12(1-x^2)$$

(in the given system of coordinates)

Comment: Thanks a ton Jean Marie I pray for your best from the deepest of my heart. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Just added a little Edit.

Comment: Seen it.thanks buddy.